# Can not Download new image and Create Emulator in Tizen Studio

Tags: tizen, tizen-tv-emulator

I have a issue when I want to create my emulator using Tizen Studio version 2.4 on Ubuntu 14.4 LTS

[image]

I can not see the platforms for Tizen TV, anw, when I choice any platform and click OK

[image]

Dialog appear without any message ! and nothing happening.

How can I resolve this issue, I want to create **Tizen TV emulator**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

finally, I find out the solution, 
I install TV Extensions-40 in Extension SDK tab, It's will create my TV emulator for me

[image]

Comment: note regardless of your platform, as mentioned here you need to start the Package Manager first and have it recognize your istalled platforms allowing an emulaor to install

Answer (score 0):

you have to visit configuration section from package manager and then enabled SDK for TV